# How to use two htaccess files?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have one script for deleting .php from url and the secound pass a username

```
# activate rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# WordPress rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# username in url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /x/profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: have you tried putting them in one file?

Comment: I use htaccess 1 day and it's not working on my localhost

Comment: oh the "not working" error - well to fix that you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super simple, combine it all into one file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Combined rules
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /x/profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: That last rule will never be matched in that position. The previous one will always catch it first.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it after post. I re-ordered it so it will work.